# How do I show end of string in SwiftUI Text within ScrollView for a changing string (without scrolling myself)?

Tags: swiftui, text, scrollview

I want to show a text just for reading, so using a Text object. In case the text is too long to fit in the frame, I want it to be scrollable, so using a ScrollView. In that same case I want the last part of the text to be shown first, so using a ScrollReader with scrollTo in onChange (thanks to @Timmy).
This works fine on initial adding to the text to scroll (button add). Scrolling however stops when resetting the text to scroll (button reset) and then starting adding text again (button add).
How to solve this so after reset text will still scroll?

```
struct ContentView: View 
{
    @State private var number = 0
    @State private var scrollText: String = ""
    
    var body: some View
    {
        VStack 
        {
            Button ("add text")
            {
                number += 1
                scrollText += "\(number)\n"
            }
            Button ("reset text")
            {
                scrollText = "reset\n"
            }
            ZStack
            {
                GeometryReader
                {
                    proxy in
                    ScrollViewReader
                    {
                        reader in
                        ScrollView
                        {
                            VStack (spacing: 0)
                            {
                                Text (scrollText)
                                    .id (1)
                            }
                        }
                        .padding (EdgeInsets (top: 10, leading: 10, bottom: 10, trailing: 10))
                        .frame (maxHeight: proxy.size.height, alignment: .leading)
                        .onChange (of: scrollText)
                        {
                            _ in
                            reader.scrollTo (1, anchor: .bottom)
                        }
                    }
                    RoundedRectangle (cornerRadius: 10)
                        .stroke (.black, lineWidth: 1)
                }
            }
            .padding (EdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: left, bottom: 0, trailing: right))
        }
        .frame (width: 400, height: 200)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you can set the offset of the ScrollView to the maximum value, so that the bottom of the content is initially visible. here is a little update to your code:

struct ContentView: View {
private var longText = "This\nis\na\ntext\nwhich\nI\nwant\nto\nbe\ndisplayed\nwith\nbottom\ntext\nvisible\non\nappearance"

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Text(longText)
                }
                .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
                .padding(.bottom, proxy.size.height)
                .offset(y: -proxy.size.height)
            }
            .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 10, leading: 10, bottom: 10, trailing: 10))
            .frame(maxHeight: proxy.size.height, alignment: .leading)
            
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                .stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 1)
        }
    }
    .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 300, leading: 30, bottom: 300, trailing: 30))
}
```

}

Comment: using .offset shifts the text outside the frame. That's not a working solution

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding offsets and messing up the view, you can use `ScrollViewReader` to scroll to the bottom of your text:

```
ScrollViewReader { reader in
    ScrollView {
        Text(longText)
            .id(1)//any id. 1 for simplicity
        Spacer ()
    }.padding(EdgeInsets (top: 10, leading: 10, bottom: 10, trailing: 10))
    .frame(maxHeight: proxy.size.height, alignment: .leading)
    .onAppear {
        reader.scrollTo(1, anchor: .bottom)
    }
}
```

The above code scrolls your `ScrollView` to show the `View` with id 1 & anchors it to the bottom when it appears.

Comment: This looks good. However, this appears to work only on first view update. What I forgot to tell/ask is that this view is called repeatedly with different sizes of longText. In that case, the updated Text does not show its bottom text. Could .onAppear be .onChange or something like that?

Comment: Yes `onChange` can be used!

Comment: onChange works fine but somehow scrolling stops after resetting the text. I updated my original question. Any ideas?

Comment: Response from Apple: I took a look at sample code, and it does seem to be a bug within ScrollViewReader. From what I’ve seen, it only happens on iOS 16.0 and later. I test on iOS 15.4 and 15.0 and I was unable to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I submitted a bug report...